# how to precompile sass with gruntjs?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, webstorm

There seem to be a few plugins...and I'm using webstorm file watcher which also precompiles individual files.

I think this may not be the best way to setup a watcher.

I'm running this command now:

`sass --no-cache --update --stop-on-error --trace ./app/sass:./app/css`

It seems to conflict with the webstorm file watch, which appears to be appending everything to `base.css`. Can someone tell me what exactly this command is doing vs. a sass filewatcher in webstorm?

What's the best way to work with sass:

- precompile my sass to css using a grunt build task
- and have file watchers while developing?

My base.sass looks like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* DO NOT EDIT FILES IN ./css. See ./sass instead */

@import "page";
@import "modal";
@import "nav";
@import "tables";
@import "forms";
@import "message";
```

Comment: Where is your gruntjs file ? What are you using grunt for? If you want to move to grunt there are some cool things you can do, if you can disable the sass filewatcher in webstorm.

I'm using grunt exclusively with Coffeescript, Sass and Bourbon....

Answer (score 1):

Your command just compiles all files in diretory `./app/sass` to CSS and put the resultant files to `./app/css`. Default file watcher runs the following command:

```
sass --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

i.e. it takes the current file (the one that has been changed) as input and creates a .css in the same directory. But, as you have 'track only root files' option on (default settings), the watcher creates css for the root file only - the one that reference other files via imports. You can turn this option off to change the current behavior ans get css generated for other files as well.